# bootstrap not next to each other with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I have a webpage where I have implemented bootstrap4 and fullpage.js,
now when I add `bootstrap col` to a sections,I get the section one below the other instead of next to each other.

this is my html

```
<div class="container-fluid position-relative">
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="row section homeClass" id="home">HomePage</div>
    <div class="row section productsClass" id="products">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 left">.col-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 right">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row section contactClass" id="contact">Contact</div>
    <div class="row" id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

my fullpage.js initialization

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke']
        /*Adding function to display the current nav-item using afterLoad Callback -> fullPage.js*/

    , afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
        var loadedSection = $(this);
        if (index == 1) {
            $('.selectedMenu').remove();
            $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active selectedMenu animated fadeInRight\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + "Home" + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
        }
        if (index == 2) {
            $('.selectedMenu').remove();
            $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active selectedMenu animated fadeInRight\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + "Products" + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
        }
        if (index == 3) {
            $('.selectedMenu').remove();
            $(".navbar-brand").after(" <ul class=\"navbar-nav\"><li class=\"nav-item active selectedMenu animated fadeInRight\"> <a class=\"nav-link\" href=\"#\">" + "Contact" + "<span class=\"sr-only\">(current)<\/span><\/a> <\/li><\/ul> ");
        }
    }

});
```

[image: this is my output]

PS: The div in black and red is my navbar and has a z-index greater than the rest of the elements in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the problem was but i was be able to fix it using this code

```
      <div class="section productsClass" id="products">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
                <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What i changed here is i put the container-fluid inside the section div and instead of having the row class inside the section div I put it in a separate div

Comment: that was so simple and I was breaking my head for past 2 hour. putting the `row` inside of the section also only. is this given in the documentation of `fullpage.js`?

Comment: @this.Believer I'm not sure if its in the documentation of fullpage.js. Did you try to use the inspector tool in the webbrowser?

Comment: I used. It's not working with the help of your answer. Thanks bud :)